# How to create a convex hull in R based on the larger of two shapefiles' extents?

Tags: r, convex-hull

In R, I have two shapefiles: Shapefile A represents roads (polylines), Shapefile B some location (points). I want to plot the convex hull enclosing the study region, and it has to be set to the larger of the extents of the two shapefiles.

To produce the convex hull, I use the `gConvexHull` function (out of the `rgeos` package) within a function I have written, which preliminary checks which of the two extents is larger using a simple if/else evaluation:

```
if(extent(points) > extent(polylines)){
    region <- gConvexHull(points)                            
  } else {
    region <- gConvexHull(polylines)                              
  }
```

It seems that the extent of the polyline shapefile is actually larger:

```
extent(points) > extent(polylines)
[1] FALSE
```

The details about the two extent are as follows:

```
> extent(points)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : 443314 
xmax        : 459959.1 
ymin        : 3963496 
ymax        : 3976765 
> extent(polylines)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : 439326.4 
xmax        : 458996.4 
ymin        : 3963185 
ymax        : 3983645
```

This should imply (at the best of my understanding) that the points should all fall within the polylines' convex hull. Yet, I cannot understand why some points fall well outside the convex hull based on the polyine extent (see image). With teference to the image attached, I am quite happy with the convex hull, but I would like it to be larger toward south-est, in order to include the few points left outside.

[image]

Comment: Could you include the output of `extent(points)` as well as that of `extent(polylines)`

Comment: I have edited the question, reporting the output of the extent() function.

Comment: I dont think you can compare extents like that: `extent(c(0, 20, 0, 20)) > extent(c(0,10,0,10))` returns `FALSE`.

Comment: If you want the area of an extent, use this function: `earea = function(e){(e@xmax-e@xmin)*(e@ymax-e@ymin)}` - you can then compare areas to get the biggest. But I'm not sure that's what you want. I suspect you want the union of the extents...

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, which is along the lines of what @Spacedman suggested in his comment. I used the `union()` function out of the `raster` package.

```
ch <- union(gConvexHull(points), gConvexHull(polylines))
```

where `ch` is the final convex hull, which is the logical union of the convex hulls enclosing each individual shapefile. As already mentioned, `gConvexHull` is a function of `rgeos` package.

Comment: `ch` won't be a "convex hull", and could even be a concave shape. Sure that's what you want?

Comment: I think you'd need to run the convex hull command one more time to get the actual convex hull of the 'combined' shape. `gConvexHull(ch)` should do it.